# Unable to understand C function call

Tags: c, function

I have a function with definition :

```
int foobar(char *ptr,...)
```

the function call is as follows :

```
int (*fooptr) (char *,...) = foobar;
```

I am not able to understand how is the function getting called ...
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's not a function call.

It is declaring a *function pointer* variable called `fooptr` that holds the address of the function.

To call that function via the pointer you would do e.g.:

```
int return_value = (*fooptr)(char_ptr, x, y, z);
```

Comment: `declaring` and `instantiating` also?

Comment: @hari - a variable _declaration_ can also _initialise_ the variable.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a call.  It is a *declaration* of `fooptr`.

Answer (score 0):

The function is not getting called with the code you have posted. The first line is the function declaration, the second is creating a pointer to it. To call it you have to use `foobar(myCharPtr[, other arguments])` or `fooptr(myCharPtr[, other arguments])`.

Answer (score 0):

The function is not getting called in your example. Its address is stored in the `fooptr` variable, which is a function pointer. If you later call that function pointer while it's still pointing to `foobar` function, it'll call `foobar` function.

You can write the second line as:

```
// declare fooptr as a variable of type function pointer 
// taking (char*,...) and returning int
int (*fooptr) (char *,...);  
// take the address of foobar function and assign it to fooptr
fooptr = &foobar;
```

to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [varargs function](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx11b.html), which can receive a variable number of parameters (similar to [printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/)). the second line you give is an assignment, not a function call.